# How Today extension App trigger container app code

Tags: ios, iphone

My app using GPS background mode, and contain a Today extension App.

I want the Today extension App trigger container app to start GPS code in background, but don't open container app.

I know openURL:, but it will open the container app in foreground.

Comment: There is no other way to do. If you use `openURL` to open application than it will always comes to the foreground. You can do background stuff after container application comes in foreground.

Comment: @Kampai Thanks, but i want my users finish work with Today extension, don't open the application.